# bash variable inserting quotes in middle of string

Tags: bash, variables, curl, amazon-s3

I am doing a scrape of a site which requires authentication to request a URL which then gives me a signed request of where the file actually is.  The problem is that when I attempt to retrieve the actual data location (a signed AWS S3 URL), there are quotes inserted randomly into the string so it never actually downloads as the string is incomplete.

```
download_url="`echo "${line}" |cut -d\] -f2-99 |tr -d '"\t'`"
curl -J -s -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" -D headers.tmp "${download_url}" > /dev/null
download_url="`grep "Location:" headers.tmp |cut -d\  -f2`"
curl -o "./${path}" -s -- "'"${download_url}"'"
```

I then end up with a command that looks like this:

```
curl -o './projects/abc-co/project 42/Design/Concepts/master_layouts.psd' -s --  "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/data/53a9d8b3ec9920e46f0d81daa6?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ33IXO7ER3UCQ6TA&Expires=1428809754&Signature=KnImZ4%2FK%2FptJwTlZVwlV%2FktA8KQ%3D&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B"ilename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27master_layouts.psd"
```

**Note:** it's **"ilename** instead of **filename** 
I thought maybe it was the method in which I was quoting the download_url, but it seems to only happen when the URL is fairly long.  It never fails on the first curl command, only the signed S3 bucket URL.

**EDIT**: I forgot the **-s --** in the second code section originally.
Also, if I do a simple:

```
echo "${download_url}"
```

afterwards, no random quotes are inserted.  It only happens during the actual command.  I also tried echoing it all to a log and then tailing it via:

```
tail -f log |grep -A1 curl | while read line;
do
    if [ `echo "${line}" |grep -c "^curl"` -gt 0 ]; then
        cmd="`echo -n "${line}" | cut -d\" -f1-3 | tr -d "\n" | tr '"' "'"`"
    elif [ `echo "${line}" | grep -c "^https:"` -gt 0 ]; then
        eval "${cmd}" "${line}"
    fi;
done
```

But no luck here either.

Comment: Can't you do a `sed s/"/\\"/g` on the string? Are there quotes present in any variables you're using?

Comment: If you mean download_url="`grep "Location:" headers.tmp |cut -d\  -f2`" | sed "s/\"/\\"/g" all that does is cause an error when curl attempts to run saying no URL was specified at all.

Comment: Execute using `bash -x /path/to/script` you may notice the error instantly.

Answer (score 0):

This "answer" is more of comment, but to have easily readable code, I'm writing an incomplete answer. *It would be help if your question included exact examples of the output you are getting with out any interruption from shell processing. (Can you add some of that please?)* Something like result of

```
 cmd_that_generates_problem_strings > problemStrings.txt
 cat problemStrings.txt
```

and then copy/paste what you find into your question. It might also help to use a comment line to indicate the problem, i.e.

```
 outputstring"with_mismatched"_dbl-qoutes" 
 #-----------^----match------^-----------^---uh?
```

Of course, if there is private information embedded, feel free to sub in XYZ etc to obfuscate the private data, but leaving the core problem in place.

In any case, I would remove a few opportunities for errors, by rewriting this to use modern (circa 1995) command substitution using `$( cmd ...)` instead of ` cmd ...` AND remove the dbl-quotes around your assignment of variables values, i.e.

```
download_url=$(echo "${line}" |cut -d\] -f2-99 |tr -d '"\t')
curl -J -s -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token}" -D headers.tmp "${download_url}" > /dev/null
download_url=$(grep "Location:" headers.tmp |cut -d\  -f2)
curl -o "./${path}" -s -- "${download_url}"
```

Some other things don't ring right in this code, i.e.

```
|cut -d\] -f2-99
```

fields delimited by ']' char, from 2 through 99? That seems like a wide file with an incredible amount of bracketing. Again, with real sample data, it will be easier to help.

```
tr -d '"\t'
```

delete all dbl-quotes and tab chars? Maybe this relates to errors you were getting because of wrapping the assignment to download_url in dbl-quotes, and is throwing off the cmd-line parser. (Sorry, I don't have the patience to construct a test on this)

Again, show us some unprocessed URLS that you are working with, and maybe we can help.

Good luck!